# Java repaint()/update()

Tags: java, graphics

just working on some code to do with java graphics, very simple example from a lecture I had today. Anyway, the internet seems to say that update will not be called by a System trigger such as resizing a frame etc. In this example, update is called by such a trigger (hence update and paint are called when I only expect paint to be called). He seemed to put it down to Operating Systems and different results on each.

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Working on windows 7

Thanks in advance

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great article that really says it all:

> http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/
>
> **1) Painting in AWT**
>
> To understand how AWT's painting API works, helps to know what
>   triggers a paint operation in a windowing environment. In AWT, there
>   are two kinds of painting operations: system-triggered painting, and
>   application-triggered painting.
>
> **2) System-triggered Painting**
>
> In a system-triggered painting operation, the system requests a
>   component to render its contents, usually for one of the following
>   reasons:
>
> - The component is first made visible on the screen.
> - The component is resized.
> - The component has damage that needs to be repaired. (For example, something that previously obscured the component has moved, and a
>     previously obscured portion of the component has become exposed).
>
> **3) App-triggered Painting**
>
> In an application-triggered painting operation, the component decides
>   it needs to update its contents because its internal state has
>   changed. (For example,. a button detects that a mouse button has been
>   pressed and determines that it needs to paint a "depressed" button
>   visual).
>
> **4) The Paint Method**
>
> Regardless of how a paint request is triggered, the AWT uses a
>   "callback" mechanism for painting, and this mechanism is the same for
>   both heavyweight and lightweight components. This means that a program
>   should place the component's rendering code inside a particular
>   overridden method, and the toolkit will invoke this method when it's
>   time to paint.